# Realtek rtl8812au WiFi broke after 20.04 kernel update

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek

I have a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8811AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter which was working fine on my Ubuntu 20.04. After a recent update it stopped working. I tried following similar steps to what I had to used to get it working in the first place but no go.

```
(base) ~/Software$ dkms status
nvidia, 450.102.04, 5.4.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 450.102.04, 5.8.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 450.102.04, 5.8.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 5.4.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 5.8.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, 1.0: added
```

This is the result of `dkms status`. How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot and use the Grub menu Advanced Options to boot into the 5.4.0-58 kernel.  Then in terminal

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.8.0-38-generic linux-generic-hwe-20.04
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

Reboot